# Is it possible to create a non-centered Javascript alert box?

Tags: javascript

For a standard Javascript `alert()` box, is it possible to have it appear in a position other than the center of the screen? Can you specify horizontal and/or vertical position?

Comment: (Yes, I'm aware that alert() is a terrible UI choice. I have a harmless prank in mind.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Afaik, it cannot be positioned where you want it.

Instead of using the default js alert box, you can always use one of the JS framework / toolkit solutions that offer way more in terms of functionality and customization.

I'm personally a fan of [jQuery](http://www.jQuery.com) and [jQueryUI](http://www.jqueryui.com)

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, I would personally discourage you from using Javascript alert() boxes altogether - they look 1995-ish and don't provide for a nice, customizable user experience. Instead, like the other poster suggested, use a standard Javascript library that will allow you to pop up a "modal" floating DIV, as well as paint a semi-transparent color all over the background, which will make for a beautiful, understandable, easy-to-use user interface.