# How to customize the position of an alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using an alert box to alert some messages after some validation.
Now I want to make alert box position over the control where it had a validation 
error.

As a default, an alert box pops up in center of page,
Now I want it at some custom position, 
for example I have 4 textbox to be validated, textbox-3 has some incorrect data, 
I want the alert to be presented just above the textbox-3 instead of center of page.

Is this possible to change the display behavior of alert box?
If there's no other option to go for jquery dialog box.

Comment: why not creating custom alert box? i really hate that ugly `alert`

Comment: exactly, but its all over the page.

Comment: For costume alert box check this http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since that is a default dialog box, you cannot position that. However, you can design your own custom alert box and position that. Or, you can use 3rd party dialog boxes, jquery ui has a nice one: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Any div can be used as a dialog with jquery, show hide functions. You can find examples here: http://www.queness.com/post/1696/create-a-beautiful-looking-custom-dialog-box-with-jquery-and-css3

Comment: I'm glad it helped you :) wish you success

Answer (score 2):

Jquery dialog box is the best option u get.Follow this:

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

[Is it possible to create a non-centered Javascript alert box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368514/is-it-possible-to-create-a-non-centered-javascript-alert-box)

Answer (score 1):

### **Not possible. You cannot change the default alerts in the browser.**

However, if you want you can create one for yourself with following options.

---

If You don't want to use 3rd party plugin
go with this

Using HTML, CSS and JS : [Click Here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp) or [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_delete_modal.asp)

---

If you want to use a separate library for dialogs with full control? [Click Here](https://www.sitepoint.com/14-jquery-modal-dialog-boxes/)

---

If you wish to use 3rd party Plugin then there are many options available :

Using jQuery : [Click Here](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Using Bootstrap : [Click Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/) or [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

Materialize CSS : [Click Here](https://materializecss.com/modals.html#!)

and Many more UI component libraries like PrimeNG, KendoUI etc

---