# How to customize the Javascript's confirm() box

Tags: javascript, confirm

How does stackoverflow customize the `confirm()` box's buttons and add custom text to the buttons?

[image]

All the other questions I looked at pointed at a random `jQuery` plugin to do this. Can this be done with Vanilla Javascript? If yes, then how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize the position of an alert box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978713/how-to-customize-the-position-of-an-alert-box)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are only specific messages/buttons you can offer the user, without using a custom alert box/plugin. They are:

1. To display a message with just an <kbd>OK</kbd> button, by calling:

   ```
   window.alert('Message');
   ```
2. To display a message with <kbd>OK</kbd>/<kbd>Cancel</kbd> as the options, by calling:

   ```
   var didTheyPressOK = window.confirm('Are you sure you want to XXXXX?');
   ```
3. **As StackOverflow does in your example**, to display a <kbd>Leave...</kbd>/<kbd>Stay...</kbd> message on leaving the page, where pressing <kbd>Stay</kbd> causes the browser to stay on your page (the exact button wording is browser-dependent, you cannot control it):

   ```
   window.onbeforeunload = function() {
       // you may or may not want a condition here, e.g.
       // if (thereAreUnsavedChanges)
       return 'Are you sure you actually want to leave? You have unsaved changes...';
   }
   ```

For any other situation, you'll need to use some kind of alert plugin (or write one yourself :-/), as you speculated in your question.

---

Put simply, those buttons are browser specific and chrome automatically displays helpful text on the button to make things clearer. It happens with `window.onbeforeunload` if you return a string, which is displayed as a message before navigation.

Comment: If that's not possible then how does SO achieve this?

Comment: @Aniket Like I said, the only thing you can do is display a Leave/Stay message when the user is about to leave the page (or an OK/Cancel message at any time). The Leave/Stay is what Stack Overflow does. There is no way to customize what those two buttons actually say – they are set by the browser.

Comment: So what plugin is stackoverflow using to get this functionality? ALA can I see the code that does this in SO

Comment: @Aniket I don't know how many ways I can say this... They are using code like the code I gave in my answer. Not a plugin. Just a `window.onbeforeunload = function() { return '...'; }`  Here is a working example that duplicates what StackOverflow does, just go to this link and then close the tab/go to a different web page: http://jsfiddle.net/5CXbS/ ...StackOverflow have no control over those two buttons, in Google Chrome they can only say 'Leave this page'/'Stay on this page', in other browsers they may be different but again you can't control them.

Comment: All I really needed was this line: `the exact button wording is browser-dependent, you cannot control it`

Comment: thanks, I thought it was some sort of browser hack -