# Position Alertbox in middle of scrolled iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I developed a website which is used on an other domain in an iframe.
The page is very long (a lot of pictures) and scrolled from the parent.

Now i want to display a alert box in the middle of the maybe scrolled frame, how could that be done?

Comment: You can do this using positioning.

Comment: I made a little demo of a way you could do this. [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/9je7d/). So its using `position: fixed` this will keep in fixed in the middle no matter what you are doing (scrolling). So take a look, click anywhere to make the popup appear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize the position of an alert box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978713/how-to-customize-the-position-of-an-alert-box)

Comment: is this also working if my page is an iframe?