# centering a window.confirm dialog box on the screen

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have the following dialog box that is working correctly, however, I can't get it to center on the page:

```
<Button variant="danger" onClick={() => { if (window.confirm('Delete character?')) handleCharacterDeletion(row.original) }}>DELETE</Button>
```

The box appears on the top of the page, but I want it centered in the middle.

I tried wrapping the whole thing in a  tag, but that actaully didn't do one little thing.

Is there way to get my dialog centered?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize the position of an alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978713/how-to-customize-the-position-of-an-alert-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to center a [Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) interface (ex: window.alert, window.confirm...) because it's native to your web-browser.

However, you can make a modal with libraries ([Micromodal](https://github.com/Ghosh/micromodal), [Fancybox](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox)) or from scratch.