# is it possible to reposition alert box or put animation on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to put animation on the alert box, i did this but it does nothing, i tried searching the web but did not find any info on this, is it possible to put animation an alert box?

```
 alert(' ur message');


window.alert = function (message) {
    if (parent.moveBy) {
        for (i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
            for (j = n; j > 0; j--) {
                parent.moveBy(i, 0);
                parent.moveBy(0, -i);
                parent.moveBy(-i, 0);
                parent.moveBy(0, i);
                parent.moveBy(i, 0);
                parent.moveBy(0, -i);
                parent.moveBy(-i, 0);
                parent.moveBy(0, i);
                parent.moveBy(i, 0);
                parent.moveBy(0, -i);
                parent.moveBy(-i, 0);
                parent.moveBy(0, i);
                parent.moveBy(i, 0);
                parent.moveBy(0, -i);
                parent.moveBy(-i, 0);
                parent.moveBy(0, i);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: A short answer: no. You've to implement your own, `parent` in your script is `undefined`. Please do some search, there are plenty of choices.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the native JavaScript alert box. Its implementation will vary from browser to browser. However, you are always free to create your own alert box element and animate that. There are also plenty of customizable libraries you can find online, such as [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/).

Also see:

- [How to customize the position of an alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978713/how-to-customize-the-position-of-an-alert-box)
- [Is it possible to create a non-centered Javascript alert box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368514/is-it-possible-to-create-a-non-centered-javascript-alert-box)
- [positioning the prompt popup in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053028/positioning-the-prompt-popup-in-javascript)